# Restangular get one

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I think I am having trouble understanding Restangular. I am able to get all, but I can't get one.

I have tried both:

```
getById: function(id){
  return Restangular.one('user').get({user_id: id});
}
```

and:

```
getById: function(id){
  return Restangular.one('user', id).get();
},
```

Both result in the browser crashing from too much recursion.

The base url is already set.

Answer (score 3):

It was indeed my misunderstanding. I still don't fully understand Restangular, but I do now know I needed to use:

```
Restangular.all('user')
```

And, more specifically, in my case:

```
getById: function(id){
  return Restangular.all('user').get('?user_id=' + id);
},
```